# How to break protein sequence into equal size of 20 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to break the structure of protein into the chunks of 20 equal size 
the structure of the protein is something like this

```
MASTEGANNMPKQVEVRMHDSHLGSEEPKHRHLGLRLCDKLGKNLLLTLTVFGVILGAVCGGLLRLASPI
HPDVVMLIAFPGDILMRMLKMLILPLIISSLITGLSGLDAKASGRLGTRAMVYYMSTTIIAAVLGVILVL
AIHPGNPKLKKQLGPGKKNDEVSSLDAFLDLIRNLFPENLVQACFQQIQTVTKKVLVAPPPDEEANATSA
VVSLLNETVTEVPEETKMVIKKGLEFKDGMNVLGLIGFFIAFGIAMGKMGDQAKLMVDFFNILNEIVMKL
VIMIMWYSPLGIACLICGKIIAIKDLEVVARQLGMYMVTVIIGLIIHGGIFLPLIYFVVTRKNPFSFFAG
IFQAWITALGTASSAGTLPVTFRCLEENLGIDKRVTRFVLPVGATINMDGTALYEAVAAIFIAQMNGVVL
DGGQIVTVSLTATLASVGAASIPSAGLVTMLLILTAVGLPTEDISLLVAVDWLLDRMRTSVNVVGDSFGA
GIVYHLSKSELDTIDSQHRVHEDIEMTKTQSIYDDMKNHRESNSNQCVYAAHNSVIVDECKVTLAANGKS
ADCSVEEEPWKREK
```

I have tried the by iterating loop

```
    x="abfgjjhuyuryitfvbkjuhhgyuumnabcdfrfhghhoiutgfctrdgfvijnk"
    length=len(x)
    values= [length/20+1]

    a=1
    for i in length(a,x)
    print(i)
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this by importing the textwrap

```
import textwrap
myArray="MASTEGANNMPKQVEVRMHDSHLGSEEPKHRHLGLRLCDKLGKNLLLTLTVFGVILGAVCGGLLRLASPIHPDVVMLIAFPGDILMRMLKMLILPLIISSLITGLSGLDAKASGRLGTRAMVYYMSTTIIAAVLGVILVLAIHPGNPKLKKQLGPGKKNDEVSSLDAFLDLIRNLFPENLVQACFQQIQTVTKKVLVAPPPDEEANATSAVVSLLNETVTEVPEETKMVIKKGLEFKDGMNVLGLIGFFIAFGIAMGKMGDQAKLMVDFFNILNEIVMKLVIMIMWYSPLGIACLICGKIIAIKDLEVVARQLGMYMVTVIIGLIIHGGIFLPLIYFVVTRKNPFSFFAGIFQAWITALGTASSAGTLPVTFRCLEENLGIDKRVTRFVLPVGATINMDGTALYEAVAAIFIAQMNGVVLDGGQIVTVSLTATLASVGAASIPSAGLVTMLLILTAVGLPTEDISLLVAVDWLLDRMRTSVNVVGDSFGAGIVYHLSKSELDTIDSQHRVHEDIEMTKTQSIYDDMKNHRESNSNQCVYAAHNSVIVDECKVTLAANGKSADCSVEEEPWKREK"
list_string = str(myArray)
textwrap.wrap(list_string, 20)
```

**the output is something like this!**

```
['MASTEGANNMPKQVEVRMHD',
 'SHLGSEEPKHRHLGLRLCDK',
 'LGKNLLLTLTVFGVILGAVC',
 'GGLLRLASPIHPDVVMLIAF',
 'PGDILMRMLKMLILPLIISS',
 'LITGLSGLDAKASGRLGTRA',
 'MVYYMSTTIIAAVLGVILVL',
 'AIHPGNPKLKKQLGPGKKND',
 'EVSSLDAFLDLIRNLFPENL',
 'VQACFQQIQTVTKKVLVAPP',
 'PDEEANATSAVVSLLNETVT',
 'EVPEETKMVIKKGLEFKDGM',
 'NVLGLIGFFIAFGIAMGKMG',
 'DQAKLMVDFFNILNEIVMKL',
 'VIMIMWYSPLGIACLICGKI',
 'IAIKDLEVVARQLGMYMVTV',
 'IIGLIIHGGIFLPLIYFVVT',
 'RKNPFSFFAGIFQAWITALG',
 'TASSAGTLPVTFRCLEENLG',
 'IDKRVTRFVLPVGATINMDG',
 'TALYEAVAAIFIAQMNGVVL',
 'DGGQIVTVSLTATLASVGAA',
 'SIPSAGLVTMLLILTAVGLP',
 'TEDISLLVAVDWLLDRMRTS',
 'VNVVGDSFGAGIVYHLSKSE',
 'LDTIDSQHRVHEDIEMTKTQ',
 'SIYDDMKNHRESNSNQCVYA',
 'AHNSVIVDECKVTLAANGKS',
 'ADCSVEEEPWKREK']
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
values = [x[i:i+20] for i in range(0, len(x), 20)]
```

Just as a reference:

`x[a:b]` takes a slice of the string `x` from the index `a` up to (but not including) index `b`, therefore `x[i:i+20]` takes a slice of size twenty starting from index `i`.

`range(a, b, step)` would generate a sequence of numbers from `a` up to (but not including) `b` with increments of `step`.

Comment: I think a closing square bracket is missing at the end. ']'

Comment: I think you should increase `i` by `len(x)/20` instead of `20`. Cause the question said "20 equal size" not 20 characters.

Comment: I think the OP (@sania-kareem) should weigh in here, because the question is a bit vague. You might be right, or not!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall`, after first removing all whitespace, e.g.:

```
inp = """MASTEGANNMPKQVEVRMHDSHLGSEEPKHRHLGLRLCDKLGKNLLLTLTVFGVILGAVCGGLLRLASPI
HPDVVMLIAFPGDILMRMLKMLILPLIISSLITGLSGLDAKASGRLGTRAMVYYMSTTIIAAVLGVILVL
AIHPGNPKLKKQLGPGKKNDEVSSLDAFLDLIRNLFPENLVQACFQQIQTVTKKVLVAPPPDEEANATSA"""
inp = re.sub(r'\s+', '', inp)
chunks = re.findall(r'.{1,20}', inp)
```

This prints:

```
['MASTEGANNMPKQVEVRMHD',
 'SHLGSEEPKHRHLGLRLCDK',
 'LGKNLLLTLTVFGVILGAVC',
 'GGLLRLASPIHPDVVMLIAF',
 'PGDILMRMLKMLILPLIISS',
 'LITGLSGLDAKASGRLGTRA',
 'MVYYMSTTIIAAVLGVILVL',
 'AIHPGNPKLKKQLGPGKKND',
 'EVSSLDAFLDLIRNLFPENL',
 'VQACFQQIQTVTKKVLVAPP',
 'PDEEANATSA']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```py
## With protein your string containing the data
size_of_split = 20
splited_protein = list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(protein)]*size_of_split)))
```

It uses [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in a way that is described in its documentation.

To quote it :

> [...] clustering a data series into n-length groups using zip(*[iter(s)]*n).
>   This repeats the same iterator n times so that each output tuple has
>   the result of n calls to the iterator. This has the effect of dividing
>   the input into n-length chunks.